# How to simulate as if user pressed Ctrl "plus" plus or minus using javascript (JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, macos

Is this possible if I click on an anchor link to simulate as if I have pressed `Ctrl+` keys on the keyboard (or equivalent on Mac)? if yes, could you show me how to do this, please?

something like

```
<a href="#" onclick="simulateCtrlKeyPlus();return false;">Ctrl+</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to simulate the behaviour of the CTRL+Mousewheel Zoom function, you can use CSS3-Transitions. A nice jQuery plugin for this is [jquery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/).

Example:

```
$('a.ctrlplus').click(function() {
  $('body').transition({ scale: ($('body').css('scale')+0.1) });
});
```

Don't know if it works in all Browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you will need to access this on the browser API level, since not all browsers have this functionality or do it the same way.

Comment: any example? It doesn't matter if they all support or not.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand what you are going to achieve, but [here](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/) is a plugin, which made handling keyboard shortcuts very easier.

Here is an example

```
shortcut.add("Ctrl+Shift+X",function() {
alert("You have pressed Ctrl+____");
});
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: No, I don't want to check if a user has pressed them keys (instead they click on a link which simulates the behaviour of these keys)

Comment: May be it is not possible. It is a security concern.It would be easier for us to help with any alternatives if we know the exact req, which are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The exact requirement is to zoom in and out in this case. I know it already how to do this using Javascript + CSS but as Ctrl+ works wonderfully I am just interested to know if it is possible using click event and how?

Answer (score 0):

To simulate the zoom function, you can use CSS property "zoom".
For JS, it's like:

```
function simulateCtrlKeyPlus() {
   let currentZoom = parseFloat(document.body.style.zoom) || 1
   document.body.style.zoom = currentZoom * 1.1
}
```